How to accept EULA unattended for SteamCMD under debian-variants?
I am trying to auto accept in an unattended manner, the STEAMCMD package EULA
As per the following previous answer on this topic

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097393/non-interactive-steam-install-on-linux-debian-how-to-auto-accept-eula
How can I accept the Lience agreement for steam prior to apt-get install?
script auto accepting EULA / license agreement
How to automatically accept the Steam license for steamcmd?
How to accept steam license when installing steam?
command to accept VirtualBox PUEL (for virtualbox-ext-pack installation)?
How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?

The best way should be to first get the question and answers using
debconf-show steam

which should output
* steam/question: I AGREE
* steam/license:
* steam/purge:

And then using debconf-set-selections
echo steam steam/license note '' | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo steam steam/question select "I AGREE" | sudo debconf-set-selections

However, it appears this no longer works, example

I have also tried the debconf-set-selections commands above, to no effect
How to install steamcmd in a fully unattended manner ?

Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead. What happens when you install steam after running those debconf-set-selections commands?

Hi, the problem was debconf-show only has output after running apt update after adding the non-free repo

After a fresh install I have found out why debcon-show had no output
It will not show until you run apt update after adding the non-free repo
The following commands will install steamcmd without interactive interruption. On a fresh debian 12-based distro.
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm non-free >> /etc/apt/sources.list
dpkg --add-architecture i386
echo steam steam/license note '' | debconf-set-selections
echo steam steam/question select "I AGREE" | debconf-set-selections
apt update
apt install steamcmd -y

